# Concatenate list and tuple output not favourable

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop

I want to create an output that concatenates the list and tuple to give a single output

```
def conca(names,storey): 
for name in names:
    i = 0
    d = "%s has %d"%(name,storey[i])
    print(d)
    i = i+1
 conca(names=("White house","Burj khalifa",
 "Shit"),storey = [3,278,45])
```

But it gives an output like

> White house has 3
>
> Burj khalifa has 3
>
> Shit has 3

But i dont want only 3. I want i to increase. Give output like

> White house has 3
>
> Burj khalifa has 278
>
> Shit has 45

Why is i not incrementing. What am i doing wrong

Comment: Because `i = 0` is **inside the loop**. Note you can just use `for name, storey in zip(names, storeys):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:

- You define `i` inside loop, so you reset to 0 in every iteration resulting in adding first `storey` every time.

**Corrected**:

```
def conca(names, storey):
    i = 0
    for name in names:
        d = "%s has %d"%(name,storey[i])
        print(d)
        i = i+1
conca(names=("White house","Burj khalifa",
 "Shit"), storey=[3,278,45])
```

You can also use `zip()` to iterate over lists simultaneously:

```
def conca(names, storey): 
    for name, st in zip(names, storey):
        print(f'{name} has {st}')

conca(names=("White house","Burj khalifa",
 "Shit"), storey=[3,278,45])
```